# onMouseUp not working with span tag in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two div I want to send selected text to another div using onMouseUp event? Right now this is working when I'm using `<textarea>` but when I'm using `<span>` tag this is not working. There is another way to do it?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/onmouseup-not-working-with-span-tag-b01tfg?file=/src/App.js:0-1568)

Code:-

```js
import React from "react";
import { Box, Grid, TextField, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";

const SendSelectedText = () => {
  const [label1, setlabel1] = useState("");
  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    setlabel1(
      e.target.value.substring(e.target.selectionStart, e.target.selectionEnd)
    );
    // setlabel1(window.getSelection().toString());
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Box className="sendSelectedTextPage">
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xl={6} lg={6} md={6}>
            <span
              onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
              style={{ width: "100%", height: "200px" }}
            >
              The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
              normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
              content here', making it look like readable English. Many … The
              point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
              distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
              content here', making it look like readable English. Many …
            </span>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xl={6} lg={6} md={6}>
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              label="Label One"
              value={label1}
              multiline
              rows={3}
              className="sendSelectedTextPageInput"
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default SendSelectedText;
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Your `handleMouseUp` function is trying to read `e.target.value`. But the clicked span element doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: thank you @EmielZuurbier this will work window.getSelection().toString() instead of e.target.value. I got answer for this. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getSelection().toString()
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/onmouseup-not-working-with-span-tag-forked-sykdwj?file=/src/App.js